# Login -Comparing username and password to a file using the enumerate method

Tags: python-3.x

In my program, I have asked the user for certain details (ie date of birth). Details have already been written to the file "Reg and Login" after the user has registered.

I focus on the username and password in order for the user to login.  In the file, the username is written on the 4th line, index 3, and the password is written on the 5th line, index 4.

I have created a function. Within the function I used the method "enumerate" file to compare "usern" and "passw" with the existing username and password in the list.

However, there are basic logic errors -it looks at EACH line and outputs: "Username/Password is incorrect", until it finds username or password.  It always outputs  "You have not logged in"  How can I fix this?  Tried to use the enumerate method

```py
def loginF(usern,passw):
    Login = False

    f = open("Reg and Login","r")
    data = f.readlines()

    User_check = False
    Pass_check = False

    for usern, line in enumerate(data):
        if usern == 3:
            print("Username is correct")
            User_check = True

        if usern != 3:
            print("Username is incorrect")

    for passw, line in enumerate(data):
        if passw == 4:
            print("Password is correct")
            User_check = True
        if passw != 4:
            print("Password is incorrect")

    if User_check == True and Pass_check == True:
        print("You have successfully logged in")
    else:
        print("You have not logged in")
    f.close()

usern = 0
passw = 0

choice = input("Do you want to login (y/n): ")
if choice == "y":
    usern = input("Please enter your USERNAME: ")
    passw = input("Please enter your PASSWORD: ")

    print(loginF(usern,passw))
```

Comment: You have `enumerate` backwards (`usern, line`), enumerate returns `(line, element)`.  Also you are checking if the user/pass are equal to integers... That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Error - Syntactical Remorse 7 Thanks.. but by enumerating them,  I allocated each line with a number in numerical order and then compared to equal integers.. Why doesn't it make sense..

Comment: Thanks anyway appreciate it @Error - Syntactical Remorse 7

Comment: Just checking line numbers doesn't mean usernames are equal right? So is it a valid username just if the user inputs the right line number where it is saved in the file?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse No sorry should have made it clear. The username and password have already been written to the file. The variables "usern" and "pass" are compared to the file which is enumerated.

Comment: Correct but that is not what your are doing which is why you may want to look at your code again.